# SQL Server SSIS 0x80040E4D error when trying to schedule a job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I get the following error when trying to schedule a job on SQL Server. When using the elipsis button to find the package:

```
An OLE DB error 0x80040E4D (Login failed for user 'TL\sa_sql'.) occured while enumerating packages. A SQL statement as issued and failed.
```

If I use windows authentication I can use the list as normal. However I can't run the package under the server agent logon as the package requires access to a saved session for a 3rd party program (WinSCP). So I created the system admin account above and gave it all the permissions I thought were reasoanble including the SQL Server Agent permissions on MSDB. The package runs fine from Visual Studio using this login and this login can connect to the DB and to the Integration Services storage.

Comment: What ellipsis button are we talking about here? Where do you get this error message? What login does your SQL Server agent run on?\

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled jobs on MSSQL always run as the user used to start the SQL Server Agent.  Set up a service account that has appropriate rights to the server system then use that service account to start the SQL Server Agent service.

Comment: This isn't true. You can specify the user you want the job or step to run as in the Agent editor